# WinRT: Right-Click works for selecting items. Swipe Gesture doesn't

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, selection, swipe, right-click

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  I have an application which uses the 'IsSelected' property of GridViewItem to indicate that an item has been selected.  When I'm using the application on a desktop computer (no touch devices) and I right-click on the item, it becomes selected.  Take the same program and put it on a Surface and I can find no gestures that will select it.  Swipe-down, press-and-hold; nothing seems to do the work that the Right-Click does on the desktop.

Anyone have any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: Right click = swipe. So you need to set the property IsSwipeEnable = true.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got the answer and it's not pretty.  In my code, I had attempted to subclass the **GridView** with my own control called **ContentView**.  In XAML there is no subclassing of standard controls (you can't use the 'BasedOn' to pick up the style of built in controls) so my **ContentView** was not picking up the styling of a standard **GridView**.  However, after pulling apart the standard style I've discovered the two critical features are:

*IsSwipeEnabled* - Must be set to **true** for swiping to work on the item.

*ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode* - Must be **disabled** so the scroll viewer doesn't try to interpret the swipe motion as a command to scroll downward.

After that, swiping to Right-Click works easy as pie.

Comment: To clarify you can 100% subclass the `GridView`. I had to mention this so your comment does not mislead other developers who might find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you are asking. It seems counterintuitive, huh? In this situation, my preference is to enable item clicking and use item clicking to set the selected item. If find this to be the most intuitive for users. Start with this XAML:

```
<GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick" />
```

And then simply do this:

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as GridView;
    if (grid.SelectedItems.Contains(e.ClickedItem))
        grid.SelectedItems.Remove(e.ClickedItem);
    else
        grid.SelectedItems.Add(e.ClickedItem);
}
```

It should work for SelectionMode Single and Multiple just fine.

Does that make sense?

// Jerry

Comment: I agree that you can force the action using the events (you would actually want to capture the 'RightTapped' event, not the ItemClick).  However, it still doesn't make sense:  if you have a **working** gesture with a mouse, there must be some analog with a touch device.

Comment: There is, tap and drag the item down a quarter inch.